# C++/Cx passing delegates to native c++ exception thrown

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a C++/Cx library to which I need to pass a callback function from C# as a pointer to it.

The delegate is declared in WinRt layer as follows:

```
public delegate void del(int, enumType, uint, string, int);
```

C#

```
void callbackFunction(
            int a,
            enumType b,   //this is public enum class
            uint c,
            String d,
            int e)
{
     tb.Text() = d;
}

Wrc_Component.wrc w = new Wrc_Component.wrc();

del d = new d(callbackFunction);
IntPtr p = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(d);

w.func(p.ToInt32(), "string");
```

And again in WinRt layer definition of func():

```
void wrc::func(int ptrToCallback, Platform::String^ str){
    void*p = (void*)ptrToCallBack;
    callBackFunction cb = (callBackFunction)p;
    cb(0,enumType(0),0,"aaaa",0);             //here is exception thrown
}
```

Of course the code is simplified a little.
The line in which following exception is thrown is marked in a code:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Windows Runtime delegates may not be used for PInvoke interop.

I would like to mention also that if I am calling a function retrieved in the same way but much simpler it does not throw any exceptions.

What is causing this exception? Is this because of user defined enum type?

**EDIT**

And what if I need to pass it even further down to C++ native library, I can't retrieve the pointer to function from delegate in WinRt as far as i know.

Comment: Regarding your follow up question you can't pass the C# delegate into a pure C++ library. The use of C++/CX types is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As robwirving stated, you can’t just pass the function pointer to Windows Runtime component as a delegate.

The Windows Runtime delegate is different from the .NET delegate. To pass the handler from the .NET to Windows Runtime, you need to have a Windows Runtime wrapper. In your case, you can wrap through delegate del.

```
    del handler = new del((a, b, c, d, e) =>
    {
       // to change the UI element in a handler, you may need to consider using the CoreDispatcher.
       tb.Text = d;
    });

    w.func(handler, "string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the delegate functions around as native pointers. You pass them as the delegate type. Try this in your C#:

```
void callbackFunction(
            int a,
            enumType b,   //this is public enum class
            uint c,
            String d,
            int e)
{
     tb.Text() = d;
}

Wrc_Component.wrc w = new Wrc_Component.wrc();

del d = new del(callbackFunction);

w.func(d, "string");
```

And for your WinRT change to this:

```
void wrc::func(del^ myDel, Platform::String^ str){
    if(myDel)
        myDel->Invoke(0, enumType(0),0,"aaaa",0);
}
```

I believe I covered everything but I have a full blog post on this topic here: http://www.robwirving.com/2014/07/21/calling-c-methods-c-winrt-components/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that exception...

The cause of this exception was that the delegate that is declared in Windows Runtime cannot be used in C#, therefore declaring and using C# delegate solved the problem.

Additionally with the construction as in a question (except for delegate of course) I am able to pass and store function pointers in all three layers I am using.

However, if anyone sees some possible hazards in this implementation please, share with us for the better code!

Thanks to other answers provided by @Jeffrey Chen and @robwirving.

Comment: Don't you think you should be marking my answer, or @Jeffrey Chen's as the answer to this question rather than posting your own response and selecting that as the answer?

Comment: Well ok, I marked Jeffrey Chen post as an answer. But I posted mine also in order to Answer all of the questions. Cheers